# How to save image with background removal using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have original image

[image: Original image]

after preprocessing I got the image like this

[image: Processed image]

Now I want to save images without black background how can I do that?

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

def rotate_image(image, angle):
  image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
  rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
  result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  return result

img = cv2.imread('/content/52a3b700031458331e469345aaf00f27.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5),0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2_imshow(thresh)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_countour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
binary_mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [largest_countour], 0, 1, -1)
new_img = img * np.dstack((binary_mask, binary_mask, binary_mask))
minRect = cv2.minAreaRect(largest_countour)
rotate_angle = minRect[-1] if minRect[-1] < 0 else -minRect[-1]
new_img = rotate_image(new_img, rotate_angle)

cv2_imshow(new_img )
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python/OpenCV, threshold your processed image. Then get the contour of the center white rectangle. From the contour, you can get the bounding box. From the bounding box, you can crop the image using Numpy.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(new_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_countour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_countour)
new_img_crop = new_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

Comment: the bounding rect already exists in the question. it's only rotated. there's no need for cvtColor + threshold + findcontours to rediscover it.

Comment: True and a good solution to use, but then one needs to correct the rotation of the corner points from rotated to unrotated. I thought it might be easier for this OP to do this than figure out how to rotate the corner points. As usual there are often multiple ways to solve a problem

Comment: @fmw42 How this OP works? like rotated the corner points?

Comment: `@Med FutureXAI` Sorry, I do not understand the question. OP = original poster (that is you).